LDO vs voltage reference when input signal is noisy
I am designing an active EMI-filter (AEF) with an op amp (LTC6227). The AEF suppresses noise from a DC/DC converter. Ther op amp requires a supply voltage of 9V and a reference voltage of 4.5V at the positive input (half of the supply voltage).
The input voltage to the DC/DC converter is 28 VDC. I want to use this voltage to supply the op amp. 28 VDC to 9 VDC with a LDO-regulator. And 9 VDC to 4.5 VDC with a voltage reference. However, I am not sure the input voltage of 28 VDC is "clean" enough to use for this purpose. I have tried this solution with a 9V battery and a voltage reference that outputs 4.5V, and it works.
Is it a good idea to use the 28 VDC input voltage and regulate it down to 9 VDC and then supply it to the op amp? Also, would it be better to use a voltage reference instead of an LDO?


In principle, 28V linearly regulated down to 9V should be clean enough for opamp supply for the sort of application you have in mind. That said, there are things you should consider:

28V -> 9V is a fairly large drop. From what you've shown of your application, this is most likely fine. A single opamp isn't likely to present a heavy enough load to cause thermal issues. But if you do have other circuits running off the 9V, you may want to pre-regulate it down to 12V or so.
Ensure your LDO has a 'good' PSRR spec. In general, LDOs listing themselves as being suitable as switching post regulators are fine. In demanding applications, LDOs meant for RF circuits will be a whole lot cleaner, but also much more expensive.
Running one opamp off of a voltage reference may be ok, but as a general practice I wouldn't suggest it. Ultimately, you're going to be using the same switching input to the voltage reference, and the voltage reference is ultimately a linear voltage regulator. The same PSRR requirements, etc. continue to hold. References are also not designed to drive currents. Remember that whatever current (and transients) you need on AMPOUT also need to come from the power supply of the opamp.

If I were designing your circuit, I'd use an LDO for the opamp power supply and a voltage reference with the output of the LDO as the input to generate a clean 4.5V reference. And I'd use the same voltage reference signal wherever else it is needed. If the reference is driving something with switched capacitor inputs or something else needing large currents or transients, I'd use opamp buffers, powered by the 9V, to create clean copies of the same 4.5V reference.

Voltage references usually have only tiny output currents, so if your application is not something really special with very low output current if the opamp acceptable, you can't use voltage reference directly.
You could use some amplifier (instrumentation amp or some zero-drift amp) with high PSSR spec and use it as unity gain or low gain (2?) circuit, with reference on the input and supply it from the 28V. But in this case you completely rely on PSSR, the ability of the opamp to filter the power supply noise out. This is usually used for getting the highly stable voltage with more output current than reference could provide.
Since there is quite a lot of voltage difference between your input and output, i would look into good LDOs. There are loads out there, just make sure you dont only look at PSSR spec but rather the frequency response of PSS. Use the ones that have high PSSR at frequency that you need to filter more.
You could also look into LPFs using capacitance multiplier, considering that there is really enough headroom in voltage.
For all this tou also need to consider current and thermal budgets, and usually also budget in terms of unit cost.
Probably some combo will be used in the end, if very stable voltage is required i would imagine also using amp+ref circuit I mention before (usually as a last stage).
